# Do 4byte aligned pointers use any padding?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-alignment

I stumbled on an "hacky" answer recently ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435444)) where it was mentioned that because (I assume 32bit) C/C++ pointers are usually 4byte aligned the last 2 bits of each pointer are always zero. I don't understand why this should be the case. Why not use all 32bits to represent an address?

Please disregard the merits of the actual answer I linked to above. I'm only interested in the observation regarding the 2 LSBs.

Comment: Recent JVMs actually make use of this (see [CompressedOops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)) - since they know those bits will be zero, they can use shifting with 32 bit pointers to address more than 2^32 bytes of memory. But they can guarantee those bits will always be zero, which in most cases may be more of a hassle than the memory you save is worth.

Comment: You do use all 32-bits to represent an address. But since the addresses are always a multiple of 4, the last two bits of the address are always zero. It's the same with decimal. If your numbers are always a multiple of 10, the last two digits will always be zero.

Comment: Why are the addresses always a multiple of 4? A multiple of 2 is all that's required to achieve 4-byte alignment. So, once again, why not use all 32 available bits to store pointer addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may notice the key word "usually" in that statement. "Usually" does not imply "*always*". And if something isn't always true, you can't assume it to be true and just chop off the last two bits.

Most pointers to live objects will have alignments of at least 4 bytes. However, you can create an array of `char`s, and those elements will be byte addressable. That something happens 99% of the time doesn't mean you can ignore the final 1% where it doesn't happen.

The reason why most pointers are aligned to at least 4 bytes is that most pointers are pointers to objects or basic types that themselves are aligned to at least 4 bytes. Things that have 4 byte alignment include (for most systems): `int`, `float`, `bool` (yes, really), any pointer type, and any basic type their size or larger.

Any object that contains one of these must be aligned to at least the alignment of that object. So an object that stores an `int` is aligned to 4 bytes. An object that contains a pointer is aligned to at least 4 bytes. And so forth. Rare is the object that doesn't include one of these basic types.

That's why. The vast majority of data types you want to point to will have a minimum of 4 bytes of alignment.

Comment: To expand on this slightly: the root cause of word alignment is that it allows either faster access (eg, on many CISC processors) or is required by the CPU (mostly on RISC designs), often simply because reading a value that straddles many words requires that you read all those words. Keeping the value in the minimum number of words therefore saves on memory costs.

Comment: Hi Nicol. This doesn't answer my question: I did not ask why pointers are usually 4-byte aligned but why only 30 of the 32 available bits are usually used.

Comment: @Daniel: The one leads to the other. If most of what your pointers point to is on a 4-byte (or greater) alignment, then that's 2 bits you don't usually use. Pointers point to, essentially, byte addresses in memory. If they point to things on 4-byte boundaries, then their values are multiples of 4. So the last two bits will always be zero. Hence they're unused.

Comment: Nicol: I'm still not getting it. Can you give an example, or point me to a resource that can further explain this? 

I understand that the data being pointed to is 4-byte aligned but to limit the available addresses to multiples of 4 seems unnecessarily restrictive. 

For instance, say I have 16 bits of memory and my allocator usually (not always) deals with 4-bit quantities. Then, I can have a set of addresses like: 4, 8, 12, 16 -- which is fine and all are multiples of 4. But what if the first bit is reserved? Then my available addresses might be something like: 5, 9, 13. Not multiples of 4!

Comment: Daniel: "but to limit the available addresses to multiples of 4 seems unnecessarily restrictive." The word "limit" implies a limitation, a thing that cannot happen. Re-read my first paragraph where I *explicitly state* that pointers *can* point to things outside of 4 byte alignment. "Usually" does not mean **always**. As for your example, if you reverse the first bit, then you now have pointers that are not pointing to what you thought they were. It'd be no different than adding any arbitrary number to a pointer; it doesn't go where you think it does anymore.

Comment: OK, pointers can point to things that aren't aligned. Let's set that aside for a second and assume everything being pointed to is aligned. Can you spell out for me, as though I were an idiot, why addresses in this case must be multiples of 4?

Comment: @Daniel: The definition of the term "object is X-byte aligned" is that the object's address must be a multiple of X.

Comment: This definition provides me with no insight into why. Can you point me to a proof? Why 4? For example if word size is 32bits, and I assume physical memory is organised into word-aligned chunks, shouldn't addresses pointing to aligned quantities be multiples of 32?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8051/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-daniel)

Comment: OK, I see my mistake. I forgot a single byte is the smallest addressable quantity. *headslap*. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

If the addresses you're pointing to are all four-byte aligned, then there won't be any addresses that aren't a multiple of four, or in other words the two lowest bits will always be zero. Thus, you could extremely hackily appropriate them for other purposes.